# How to add New Activity from Android GridView onItemClick?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, gridview

Check this image sample i have done it [Material Design Gridview Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vp21R.png) 
I have done the same `Material Design` for grid view `Activity` on my app, i like to add the `onItemClick` to new `Activity`,

I don't know how to do this , please give the brief explanation for the solution

res/layout/activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/android_coordinator_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/appbar_layout"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/app_bar_height"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar_android_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="@dimen/expanded_toolbar_title_margin_start"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:scaleType="centerInside"
                android:src="@drawable/code"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                app:layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier="0.7" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/nestedscrollview"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <GridView
                android:id="@+id/grid"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:columnWidth="100dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:listSelector="#00000000"
                android:numColumns="auto_fit"
                android:stretchMode="columnWidth" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

res/layout/gridview_custom_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/android_gridview_custom_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp">

    <com.andexert.library.RippleView
        android:id="@+id/more"
        rv_centered="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        app:rv_color="#fff"
        app:rv_rippleDuration="200">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/gridview_image"
                android:layout_width="80dp"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/gridview_text"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/grid_image"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Grid View Item"
                android:textColor="#444"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </com.andexert.library.RippleView>
</LinearLayout>
```

src/MainActivity.java

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout;
import android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.widget.GridView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Toolbar toolbar;
    CollapsingToolbarLayout collapsingToolbarLayoutAndroid;
    CoordinatorLayout rootLayoutAndroid;
    GridView gridView;
    Context context;
    ArrayList arrayList;

    public static String[] gridViewStrings = {
            "Android",
            "Java",
            "GridView",
            "ListView",
            "Adapter",
            "Custom GridView",
            "Material",
            "XML",
            "Code",

    };
    public static int[] gridViewImages = {
            R.drawable.android_ic,
            R.drawable.android_ic,
            R.drawable.android_ic,
            R.drawable.android_ic,
            R.drawable.android_ic,
            R.drawable.android_ic,
            R.drawable.android_ic,
            R.drawable.android_ic,
            R.drawable.android_ic
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.grid);
        gridView.setAdapter(new CustomAndroidGridViewAdapter(this, gridViewStrings, gridViewImages));

        initInstances();
    }

    private void initInstances() {
        rootLayoutAndroid = (CoordinatorLayout) findViewById(R.id.android_coordinator_layout);
        collapsingToolbarLayoutAndroid = (CollapsingToolbarLayout) findViewById(R.id.collapsing_toolbar_android_layout);
        collapsingToolbarLayoutAndroid.setTitle("Material Grid");
    }

}
```

src/CustomAndroidGridViewAdapter.java

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

/**
 * Created by HP on 5/11/2016.
 */

public class CustomAndroidGridViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;
    private final String[] string;
    private final int[] Imageid;

    public CustomAndroidGridViewAdapter(Context c,String[] string,int[] Imageid ) {
        mContext = c;
        this.Imageid = Imageid;
        this.string = string;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return string.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int p) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int p) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int p, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View grid;
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        if (convertView == null) {

            grid = new View(mContext);
            grid = inflater.inflate(R.layout.gridview_custom_layout, null);
            TextView textView = (TextView) grid.findViewById(R.id.gridview_text);
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView)grid.findViewById(R.id.gridview_image);
            textView.setText(string[p]);
            imageView.setImageResource(Imageid[p]);
        } else {
            grid = (View) convertView;
        }

        return grid;
    }
}
```

PLease give me the solution for call another Actvivty when mouse click on Image (Image 1, Image 2, etc) in Gridview this

Comment: you can add click event of imageView

Comment: can you change my code where i like to add it, i am begineer to learn android app creation so only i ask it briefly , can you do favour for me to finish my app. ??

Comment: replace your method with my method slove your issue

Comment: its work fine , but all the images will open the same activity , i like to open the different activity for each images, how can i done this ? can you guide me, can you send me the code for us

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is the code to go another activity after click on every image.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Toolbar toolbar;
CollapsingToolbarLayout collapsingToolbarLayoutAndroid;
CoordinatorLayout rootLayoutAndroid;
GridView gridView;
Context context;
ArrayList arrayList;

public static String[] gridViewStrings = {
        "Android",
        "Java",
        "GridView",
        "ListView",
        "Adapter",
        "Custom GridView",
        "Material",
        "XML",
        "Code",

};
public static int[] gridViewImages = {
        R.drawable.android_ic,
        R.drawable.android_ic,
        R.drawable.android_ic,
        R.drawable.android_ic,
        R.drawable.android_ic,
        R.drawable.android_ic,
        R.drawable.android_ic,
        R.drawable.android_ic,
        R.drawable.android_ic
};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.grid);
    gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int position, long arg3) {          
          if(gridViewStrings[position].equalsIgnoreCase(String.valueOf(1))){
            Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,SecoundActivity.class);
              intent.putExtra("image",gridViewImages[position]);
              startActivity(intent);
         }
           else if(gridViewStrings[position].equalsIgnoreCase(String.valueOf(2))){
            Intent intent2=new Intent(MainActivity.this,ThirdActvity.class);
              intent2.putExtra("image2",gridViewImages[position]);
              startActivity(intent2);
         }
       //Like this create activites how many images are there in    gridViewImages[]array.you have 9 images so create nine activities..you have to send the url in every activity from one activity to another activity according to your requirement
        }
    });
    gridView.setAdapter(new CustomAndroidGridViewAdapter(this, gridViewStrings, gridViewImages));
    initInstances();
}
private void initInstances() {
    rootLayoutAndroid = (CoordinatorLayout) findViewById(R.id.android_coordinator_layout);
    collapsingToolbarLayoutAndroid = (CollapsingToolbarLayout) findViewById(R.id.collapsing_toolbar_android_layout);
    collapsingToolbarLayoutAndroid.setTitle("Material Grid");
}
}
```

create **SecoundActivity.class**

```
  public class SecoundActivity extends AppCompactActivity{
    private ImageView image;
     @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       Intent intent=getIntent();
       int position = intent.getExtras().getInt("image");
        setContentView(R.layout.secound_view);
        image=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
      image.setImageResource(position);
}
}
```

then Finally create the **secound_view.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/image"
       />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: How to implement the above code on my project and where i to add this code , i am having 9 grid images, i like to know call another Actvity when mouse click on Image (Image 1, Image 2, etc)   ...... can you change my code its possible for you ??

Comment: yeah sure..i will

Comment: Thank you so much !!!, Please send the change code :)  [link](http://www.viralandroid.com/2016/05/android-material-design-gridview.html) check this link i am follow this website tutorial to achieve that material design , but i dont know how to call another Actvity when mouse click on Image (Image 1, Image 2, etc)

Comment: How to call another Actvity when mouse click on Image (Image 1, Image 2, etc) with different activity classess, please help me , please check this link for image for verification [link](http://www.viralandroid.com/2016/05/android-material-design-gridview.html)

Comment: i have updated the code so please past the code in your activity and follow the the answer as  i have descried.

Comment: ya sure!!, i will try it now and tell you soon , :)

Comment: its shows the secont activity layout for all the images, i like to add the code for seperate activity for each images, please help me

Comment: now check it out the updated answer. to show the clicked image in another activity

Comment: if you still could not make it out try this tutorial...http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_grid_view.htm

Comment: if i click it open same activity for all the images, i like to add different activities, each activies containes some webview option to the user \

Comment: Once update the code please kindly inform me :) @brahmy adigopula

Comment: Error:(15, 24) error: cannot find symbol variable i  , in activity class

Comment: try to import the AppCompactActivity properly.and accept the answer if it is usefull.

Comment: @AntoNavis  in place of "i" replace with "intent"

Comment: In this custom android view adapter class        public void onClick(View v) {

     Intent intent = new Intent(context,YourActivity.class);
     context.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

Comment: In this custom android view adapter class        public void onClick(View v) {

     Intent intent = new Intent(context,YourActivity.class);
     context.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });  its works and show the same activity class for all the clciked images, how can i change it in to seperate position classes

Comment: i updated the answer please follow the that.create necessary layouts and activity class according to that.i used this logic **if(gridViewStrings[position].equalsIgnoreCase(String.valueOf(1))){** to go to another activity by clicking on each image diferently

Comment: Final i found out the error on my layout design , clickable position will be changed so it takes the problem, now i am using the switch case to solve the error, but while i click the image new activity not opened, if i click right side of the image only its open how to solve it please help me

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122567/discussion-between-brahmy-adigopula-and-anto-navis).

Answer (score 2):

Replace your method with mine

```
@Override
public View getView(int p, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View grid;
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    if (convertView == null) {

        grid = new View(mContext);
        grid = inflater.inflate(R.layout.gridview_custom_layout, null);
        TextView textView = (TextView) grid.findViewById(R.id.gridview_text);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView)grid.findViewById(R.id.gridview_image);
        textView.setText(string[p]);
        imageView.setImageResource(Imageid[p]);

 imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

     Intent intent = new Intent(context,YourActivity.class);
     context.startActivity(intent);


        }
    });


    } else {
        grid = (View) convertView;
    }

    return grid;
}
```

Comment: i am having 9 grid images, i like to know call another Actvity when mouse click on Image (Image 1, Image 2, etc) ...... can you change my code its possible for you ??

Comment: its work fine , but all the images will open the same activity , i like to open the different activity for each images, how can i done this ? can you guide me

Comment: You have get position value they pass different after chack the position value your gridViewStrings[] String array position are same then get Image id and set to image imageview.

Comment: Use the *position* for each *activity* which you need to open on each image click.

Comment: how to add the position for each activity ?

Answer (score 0):

After 10 seconds in Google...
[Starting Another Activity](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html)

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, YourActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

And Click Listener/Event

```
gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
            int position, long id) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "Item Clicked: " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
});
```

Comment: can you explain it where i can add this code in above code i mention on this question ?

Comment: Setting listener should go in onCreate or (better) to onViewCreated method. Launching activity should be in onItemClick event

Answer (score 0):

In your MainActivity onCreate method, add an OnItemClick listener for the GridView:

```
gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
               // Your Intent goes here

        }
    });
```